# How can i set the font of a text as particular font?

Tags: html, fonts

How can i set the font "lulyupc" for a text? 
I must use font-family? 
I tried but it doesn't works. 
How can i use this font (and all particular font?
I must use a code like this?:

```
@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}

@font-face {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
   src: url(sansation_bold.woff);
   font-weight: bold;
}

div {
   font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

(all into css file)

Comment: Is your font being loaded? Is it in same directory as your `.css`file?

Comment: Yes, that is how you do it. Make sure that you have the file sansation_light.woff in the same folder as this css file, and also make sure you're using a browser that supports embedding fonts with woff

Comment: i have download but the format is lulyupc.ttf...

Comment: Then you should refer to the `.ttf` file and not the `.woff` file. The latter simply doesn't exist if you don't have it.

Comment: Then you need to use the correct extension in file name i.e. .ttf and not .woff

Comment: i use but it not works

Comment: You should show full sample code (including minimal HTML example), specify the browser(s) tested, and describe the origin of the font in a manner that lets others test it.

Comment: I download it from here : http://www.fontpalace.com/font-details/LilyUPC/ And i install it on /css so the code in the file /css/style.css is
    @font-face {
         font-family: LilyUPC;
         src: url(/css/LilyUPC.ttf);
    }

    And in each div i write font-family: LilyUPC;

Comment: Ok a solve thank you at all. I wrote the secondo font-family's name with  one different letter

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the font you are using is in your root directory of your website. You may even create a folder in your directory just for fonts. Also make sure you reference it's `url` correctly. If you are using an IDE like Dreamweaver then you may browse for it upon typing src.

```
@font-face {
font-family: myFirstFont;
src: url(yourfoldername/yourfontfile.woff); /*---Make sure you referenced its location right.*/
}
```